# How to create transaction to save several objects in the database?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, transactional

I have a controller in my Spring Boot application. 
The controller receives json from POST request. Parsing the json I need to create three new objects in the database:

```
    accountRepository.save(account);
    containerRepository.save(userContainer);
    containerRepository.save(operatorContainer);
```

Saving this three objects to the database should be in one transaction. 
For now I'm using `@Transactional` on controller method. However it seems the bad practice to mark controllers by @Transaction annotation. 
Should I create service where I would save three objects passed as arguments and mark the service @Transactional?
What is the best way to do it? Maybe someone can provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place for this would be in a method in your service layer.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  AccountRepository accountRepository;

  @Autowired
  ContainerRepository containerRepository;

  @Transactional
  public void save(Account account, Container userContainer, Container operatorContainer) {
    accountRepository.save(account);
    containerRepository.save(userContainer);
    containerRepository.save(operatorContainer);
  }
}
```

Then wire up the service in your controller.